# How to extract image geodata out of flickr xml image data with python?

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial, flickr

I'm researching the issue of electronic waste and I'm using this code in flickrapi py module to get an xml data on Flickr images tagged with #e-waste.

```
import flickrapi
import xml
api_key='myAPI key'
api_secret ='myAPI secret'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key,secret=api_secret)
r = flickr.photos_search(tags='e-waste', has_geo="1", per_page='100')
xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(r)
```

Running the code gives me results:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<photos page="1" pages="58" perpage="100" total="5785">
    <photo farm="3" id="13982876982" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="100231432@N02" secret="2d33e5efb1" server="2903" title="Sean Gallagher, Pulitzer Photojournalist visits MSA" />
    <photo farm="8" id="13962977066" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="100231432@N02" secret="aeb6bc1454" server="7139" title="Sean Gallagher, Pulitzer Photojournalist visits MSA" />
</photos>
</rsp>
```

Now, I want to also **get printed the geo metadata that these images should have**. How can I achieve that? I ultimately want to extract that geodata into a csv that I can then map.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `id` attribute from the `<photo>` element, then pass that to [flickr.photos.getInfo](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html) and extract data from the `<location>` element.  The example on the documentation page doesn't show this, but you can use the [API Explorer](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.getInfo) to see an example.  Here's an example from one of my photos:

```
<location latitude="38.829786" longitude="-77.52202" accuracy="14" context="0" place_id="ioKEzZ1TV7oQ55R_" woeid="2501239">
  <locality place_id="ioKEzZ1TV7oQ55R_" woeid="2501239">Sudley Springs</locality>
  <county place_id="hF2V0rlQUL9MlAlEkA" woeid="12590406">Prince William</county>
  <region place_id="pPrhG7VTUb6SbYO." woeid="2347605">Virginia</region>
  <country place_id="nz.gsghTUb4c2WAecA" woeid="23424977">United States</country>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would the REST API be.
Have a look at this:
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

You can narrow your search down with a lot of parameters. If you want to perform a geoquery, use a bbox and include the latitude/longitude in your search and narrow your search down by adding tags (#e-waste). Call each URL with url.open and pass it then to BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), a tool to parse XML.
You save yourself a step compared to the answere above:

It could look something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=5....b&per_page=250&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url)) #pass it to Beautiful Soup

for data in soup.find_all('photo'): #iterate through the XML Document
    scraping = (
    data.get("id"), #find the data you want and write it into a tuple which you then can write to a csv
    data.get("title"),
    data.get("tags"),
    data.get("longitude"),
    data.get("latitude"),
    )
```